# How do I use the css transition property to target only one instance of the background-color property?

Tags: css

I have a button that changes color when I hover and changes color again when I click it. I'm trying to use the transition property to target only the background color change of the hover and not the active one. However, the transition property targets both. Is there any solution?

```
.join-button {
    transition: 
        background-color 0.15s;
}

.join-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(5, 61, 117);
}

.join-button:active {
    background-color: rgb(2, 32, 61)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use :not(selector)

```css
.join-button:not(:active) {
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  padding: 30px;
}

.join-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(5, 61, 117);
}

.join-button:active {
  background-color: rgb(2, 32, 61)
}
```

```html
<button class="join-button">button</button>
```

Comment: Hi! I should have included all of my other css parts in the original question because I ran into a problem again. I found that the not selector affected the other css properties for the button when active, I thought that I could make another element ``` .join-button:not(:active) ``` in addition to the original ``` .join-button ``` element to specifically target the transition for background colors. However this is not working, do you have any better solutions?

Comment: You can include a minimal reproducible example of your (new) problem. Although I think you should split the transition property from the other properties when using the `:not()` selector